# Username and Pass code using parallel arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to create a pass code and username login for an app that I am designing. At the moment I am required to have four users, and four separate pass codes that are relevant to each user.
this code needs to be run in an android emulator.

Would anyone have a simple array structure that would be easy to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hristo said, you should use a `HashMap`

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
myMap.put("DmcG", "somePassword");

...

String password = myMap.get("DmcG");
```

Comment: Thank you, next time I will, but I have to call in arrays this time!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using `Hashmap`? Its structure is < Key, Value >. You can implement it by using the key for username and its value for password. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, but at the moment I need to use arrays, it's for a project.

Comment: Then make a 2D Array, what's bothering you?

Comment: I am not exactly sure how they operate. Would you have an example?

Comment: `String[][] arr = new String[4][2];
`  arr[0][0] = "username1";
`  arr[0][1] = "password1";
`  arr[1][0] = "username2";
`  arr[1][1] = "password2";
`  System.out.println("First user: " + arr[0][0]+ `arr[0][1]);
`  System.out.println("Second user: " + arr[1][0]+ `arr[1][1]);

Comment: You are welcome! Hope that works for you. If you have any problems, don't hesitate to text me.

Comment: Actually there is another part to the page I am working on, it's very annoying! It's a countdown timer, it works fine until I use it in the emulator. It won't update every second. Is there a refresh code I can use?